# Serve 404 status on angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-universal

I have a problem that is frustrating me.

I can't seem to serve 404 status with angular 5.

Steps taken:

In my server.ts, I imported

```js
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require(`./dist-server/main.${hash}.bundle`);
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import { REQUEST, RESPONSE } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
```

And Added

```js
app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) =>
    ngExpressEngine({
        bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
        providers: [
            provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
            {
                provide: REQUEST,
                useValue: options.req,
            },
            {
                provide: RESPONSE,
                useValue: options.req.res,
            },
        ]
    })(_, options, callback)
);
```

In my actual not-found component,

```js
import { Component, Inject, Injector, OnInit, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { RESPONSE } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
import { Response } from 'express';

@Component({
 selector: 'not-found',
 templateUrl: './not-found.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./not-found.component.scss']
})

export class NotFoundComponent implements OnInit {
 constructor(
  @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
  @Inject(Injector) private injector: Injector
 ) {}

 ngOnInit() {
   const response = this.injector.get(RESPONSE) as Response;
   response.status(404);
  }
 }
}
```

First of all I don't understand why I'm getting this error:
[image]

I'm running this on localhost and I'm following this implementation:
https://blog.thecodecampus.de/angular-universal-handle-404-set-status-codes/

In the comments section we're told to replace @Optional() @Inject(RESPONSE) private response: Response) with @Inject(Injector) private injector: Injector.

Answer (score 0):

The `Express` `Response` object is only provided when your code is executed server side during pre-rendering, but not once client side execution takes over. Hence the error you've got in your bwoser (clident-side)

You can directly inject the response in the constructor if you specify it as `Optional`

```
import {Optional} from '@angular/core';

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object, 
            @Inject(RESPONSE) private response: Response)
{
//Here response will be null on client side, and contain Express Response instance on server side
}
```

Or if you want to use the `Injector` instance directly (not sure why you'd want to do that, unless you've got a cyclic dependency issue), you need to do it client-side only

```
import {isPlatformServer} from '@angular/common';

ngOnInit() 
{
        if(isPlatformServer(this.platformId))//Only executes server side
        {
            const response = this.injector.get(RESPONSE) as Response;
            response.status(404);
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi @David, thanks for the response, but I did that and nothing gets executed in that if block

Comment: Are you sure? Put a `console.log` in it and check your **server** logs.

Answer (score -1):

I have my Page not found set up in my routes folder so it looks like this

`{ Path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }`

This means that any if you hit for example `mysite.com/askgdcaksgdf` you will get served with the 404 page.